# Is there a way to monitor RAM and CPU usage of Apache Spark applications?

Tags: apache-spark, monitor

I need to monitor RAM and CPU of Spark Applications that run on a stand alone Spark Cluster.

I have try to use java console and it work very well, but I need to monitor various applicationi and I need to set for each one a different java console  port .

Behind a firewalls it becomes a very long and tedious job.

Is there a way to monitor applications from Spark UI for example or something else?

Comment: Have you tried Ganglia?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ubuntu, you may use `htop`.
To install, do

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```